# how to make recursive function performs faster

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to find the 6th fibbonacci number in fibbonacci sequence . fib(6) calls fib(4) and fib(5) first fib(5) say . fib(5) calls fib(4) and fib(3) and finally reach base case and fib(2) , fib(3)  fib(4) and finally fib(5) is calculated . When fib(5) calculated fib(6) calls fib(4) . This time by same process f(2) f(3) and finally f(4) is calculated . But if we can save value for fiv(4) when fiv(5) is called , we don't need to calculate again when fiv(4)'s called . Instead we can use the saved value for fiv(4) when fiv(5) is called . How can i do that

[image]

```
int fib(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
         return 0;
    else if(n==1)
            return 1;
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

Comment: Maybe turning it into a loop might improve performance.

Comment: No one should be calculating fib number in a recursive function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ has the right idea... Iteration is typically faster than recursion. :)

Answer (score 5):

As John Zwinck has pointed out, the term is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  What it means is, in every step, we are storing the intermediate values that are calculated (because the recursive calls are expensive).

Consider your code modified as below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int fibboA[10];
    fibboA[0]=0;                 //1st Fibonacci number is always 0;
    fibboA[1]=1;                 //2nd Fibonacci number is always 1;

    cout<<fibboA[0]<<"\t"<<fibboA[1]<<"\t";

    //3rd onwards, it is the sum of the previous 2;
    for(int i=2;i<10;i++)
    {
        fibboA[i]=fibboA[i-1]+fibboA[i-2];
        cout<<fibboA[i]<<"\t";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, we are storing the previous values in the array `fibboA[]` and using the previously stored latest two values (`i-1`th and `i-2`th) while calculating the current fibonacci number (`i`).

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The term you are looking for is "[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)."  This is a quite standard optimization, for which the Fibonacci sequence is literally a textbook example.

Answer (score 1):

You get a simple and efficient (linear time) recursive solution by computing two Fibonacci numbers at a time.

```
void fib(int n, int& f1, int& f0)
{
  if (n == 1)
    { f1= 1; f0= 0; }
  else
    { fib(n - 1, f0, f1); f1+= f0; }
}
```

The function returns both `Fn` and `Fn-1`. Notice the swap of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ar[20];
int fib (int n)
{
    if(n==0||n==1)
       return n;
    if(ar[n]!=-1)//check if ar[n] exists than just return values
      return ar[n];
    else
    {
        ar[n]= fib(n-1)+ fib(n-2);
        return ar[n];
    }
}
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        ar[i]=-1;//initialise all to empty
    cout<<fib(8);
}
```

Comment: While this code is surely more optimized than the original one you posted, it is still not *fully* optimized.  When you are calling `fib(8)` in `main()`, `fib(7)`, `fib(6)` are still not evaluated and so the `ar[]` elements are still `-1`.  This code will work better when you call, say `fib(9)` again in `main()` after `fib(8)`, as the values would be present in `ar[]`.  You are optimizing your code over *many calls* and not *per call*.  My code above is optimized *per call*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more example of recursive dynamic programming solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int fib(int n, std::vector<int>& data) {
  if (n >= 2) {
    int& num = data[n - 2];
    if (num) {
      return num;
    }
    return (num = fib(n - 1, data) + fib(n - 2, data));
  }
  return n;
}

int fib(int n) {
  if (n >= 2) {
    std::vector<int> data(n - 1, 0);
    return fib(n, data);
  }
  return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << fib(23) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```